# Dynamically creating elements with text from a global property in QML

Tags: qml

I am creating some `Rectangle`s dynamically with a `Text` element inside like so:

```
Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 640; height: 480

    property var items: []
    property int count

    function push() {
        var temp = Qt.createQmlObject("import QtQuick 2.3; Rectangle {width: 100; height: 30;color: 'yellow'; Text {text: count; anchors.centerIn: parent}}", root, "")
        temp.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*200 + 1)
        temp.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*200 + 1)
        items[count] = temp
        count++
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: push()
    }
}
```

Now, whenever I call the `push` function by clicking, it creates a new rectangle with present value of `count`. But the problem is all rectangles created so far change their text to present value of `count`. I need to create rectangles with present value of count and they should not change their text when `count` changes afterwords. How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Rectangle`s you are creating have this code :

```
Text {
    text: count
    anchors.centerIn: parent
}
```

Here, there is a binding between the `text` property and `count`. So whenever the `count`changes, the `text` will reflect that change.
You need to escape the count in your string definition to actually concatenate the current value of `count` so that the code for the first item is :

```
Text {
    text: '0'
    anchors.centerIn: parent
}
```

You code shoud then be :

```
Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 640; height: 480

    property var items: []
    property int count

    function push() {
        var temp = Qt.createQmlObject("import QtQuick 2.3; Rectangle {width: 100; height: 30;color: 'yellow'; Text {text: '"+count+"'; anchors.centerIn: parent}}", root, "")
        temp.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*200 + 1)
        temp.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*200 + 1)
        items[count] = temp
        count++
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: push()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I needed just that.